# phmm blast hmmer

Tags: blast, hidden-markov-models, hmmer

i have created a phmm in hmmer from a multiple alignment focused on E. coli produced in tcoffee from sequences taken from blast similar to my query sequence.

1. I would like to ask how i can compare the results from HMMER for a pHMM against UNIPROT (i used the phmm that i created and i searched in hmmer search against uniprot) and the results from BLAST.
2. I would like to ask if i can search a pHMM in BLAST somehow, or if blast accepts only fasta one sequence.
3. Why e-values of hmmer and blast are not comparable??Why e-value in hmmer is never 0?
   Thank you so much!!

Comment: It would be useful to add the biological system you are working on. Multi-part questions don't really work, so the second part of your question is a separate question in my opinion. 1. Practicality of HMMER->UNIPROT. 2. Theories of e-values.  Blast only accepts fasta, but conversion is easy, so programmatically its doable.

Comment: thanks!yes i should create a second post. it is about E.coli. and i am trying to compare the results taken from hmmer with the results taken from blast!thanks!